# Incorrect user display of questions on user profile?

Tags: support, user-profiles, deleted-answer

I asked a question yesterday here and there were two answerers to it, of which one was deleted (I guess by the author). The question does currently display like this [on my profile page](https://superuser.com/users/91805/tex-hex):

[image]

As you can see it says “15h ago @Diogo_Rocha”. However, when I view [the question](https://superuser.com/questions/324413/which-voltage-does-the-power-on-status-and-the-hdd-activity-led-connectors-of-a-m), there is no edit, answer or anything else by Diogo.

[image]

I don’t know, but could this be related to the deleted answer?

Answer (score 5):

The (now deleted) answer by [Diogo_Rocha](https://superuser.com/users/79358/diogo-rocha) was posted about a minute after Col's answer, so your profile page is showing the last answer date/time as the activity

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer, does this mean it's a known bug or does the status get corrected when a "clean up" job is run?

Comment: I guess it'll correct itself -- although it is per se not a bug, as users who can see deleted answers are still able to click the "15h ago" link and get to the deleted post. It would make more sense not to show it though, you're right.

Comment: @TeXHeX - I'm not sure if this is a known bug or not, hence the tag [meta-tag:bug] still remains so that the devs can have a look and confirm :)

Comment: @TeXHeX seems it's bydesign